# Test if angle is in range (efficiently and elegantly)

Tags: c++, math, angle

I have an angle `phi` which I would to test for being inside (say closed, but does not matter) interval `a`, `b` in periodic `0..2pi` space. There are no restrictions on the values of `phi`, `a` and `b`, in particular:

- `a>b` is possible (e.g. a=(3/2.)pi, b=pi/;2 corresponds to the interval -pi/2...pi/2)
- if `a==b`, the interval is zero-width and only `phi==a` will be inside
- with `a-b>=2*pi`, `phi` will be always inside

I've come up with the following:

```
bool angleInside(const double& phi, double a, const double& b){
   if(std::abs(a-b)>=2*M_PI) return true; // interval covers everything
   if(a>b) a-=2*M_PI;
   if(a==b) return (fmod(a,2*M_PI)==fmod(phi,2*M_PI)); // corner case
   assert(b-a>0 && b-a<2*M_PI); // unless I overlooked something?
   // wrap phi so that a+pphi is in a..a+2*M_PI, i.e. pphi in 0..2*M_PI
   double n=(phi-a)/(2*M_PI); // n in <0..2pi)
   double pphi=(n-floor(n))*(2*M_PI);
   return pphi<(b-a);
}
```

but I am not sure if it is efficient, and perhaps if there are no libs implementing things like this.

Comment: does it work properly? just from the first look `if(a>b) a+=2*M_PI;` should not be it `b+=` or `a-=` ? also I would change `2*M_PI` with global constant `const double pi2=2.0*M_PI;` just to be sure, also `if (a==b)...` is useless if your `a<=phi<=b` is working properly. but I can miss something (if's are more consuming then FPU nowadays)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the `a+=2*M_PI`. For the `a==b`, that is necessary since there is `(p-a)/(b-a)` later, which would divide by zero.

Comment: @Glutton: "controversion"? Is there a constradition somewhere?

Comment: what does mean `p` in string `double n=(p-a)/(b-a);`?

Comment: @Glutton: should have been `phi`, fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are contradictory, in particular the condition:

> with a-b>=2*pi, phi will be always inside

Is a bit odd. Either:

1. Your range is [a,b] in modulo space, that is `a-b` will never be greater than `2pi`.
2. Your range is [a,b] if (a < b) or [b,a] if (a > b) and *then* you apply the modulo.

In any case, whenever you got a problem like this, it is convenient to think in terms of left boundary and range size, rather than left and right limits.

That is, if you can solve the problem with `a==0`, then you can just use this solution with `phi' = phi - a`, and `b' = b - a`.

Also remember that `std::remainder` (only C++11) is your friend in problems like these, because unlike `fmod` it will always produce a result in the `(-pi, pi)` range.

My proposed solution is:

```
bool angleInside(const double phi, const double a, const double b)
{
    //Case 1 above
    const double d = phi - a;
    const double s = std::remainder(b-a - M_PI, 2 * M_PI) + M_PI;

    // Or (Case 2)
    const double d = phi - std::min(a,b);
    const double s = std::fabs(b-a);


    return std::remainder( d - M_PI, 2 * M_PI ) + M_PI <= s;
}
```

Notice that in both cases is hard to get consistent results for border cases, especially when `phi` is *big* and falls in range borders modulo `2pi`.

Comment: The condition you mention is not contradictory. E.g. with a=-100pi, b=0, you cover the whole circle (50 times), or with b=0 and a=100pi you cover it something like 49 times. Note that I specifically mentioned that there are no restrictions on the values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @eudoxos, why 49 times? Is your interval open-closed? Is (phi, a, b) the same as (phi, b, a) except for borders?

Comment: ... thinking. When you have `a>b`, you can swap the limits , but also invert the result (plus use closed instead of open, if that matters). I guess I need to make the question clearer... The idea is that `-pi/2...pi/2` is the same as `3pi/2..pi/2` (not as `pi/2..3pi/2` as you seem to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If You have the possibility to change 'double phi' to a class/struct Angle, which stores the cos- and sin-value of the angle instead of the angle-value itself. Then You can easy distinguish, whether an angle alpha is on the 'right' or 'left' side of an other angle beta.
Sample:

```
struct Angle {
    Angle() : m_cos(1.), m_sin(0.) {} // 0 degree
    // some other methods
    friend double sin( const Angle& a ) { return a.m_sin; }
    friend double cos( const Angle& a ) { return a.m_cos; }
    bool operator<( const Angle& beta ) const {
        return (m_cos * beta.m_sin - m_sin * beta.m_cos) > 0.;
    }
private:
    double m_cos, m_sin;
};
```

don't know whether this make sense in Your application.
If yes, You can program an interval

```
struct Interval {
    Interval( const Angle& from, const Angle& to )
        : m_from( from ), m_to( to ), m_inner( from < to )
    {}
    friend bool in( const Angle& a, const Interval& i ) { // true, if 'a' is in ]from, to[
        if( i.m_inner )
            return i.m_from < a && a < i.m_to;
        return i.m_from < a || a < i.m_to;
    }
private:
    Angle m_from, m_to;
    bool m_inner;
};
```

.. with the function 'in' to check whether an angle 'a' is in the interval 'i'.

Please consider, that an empty (or overall full!) interval with from==to is not defined! You need a special handling in this case.